# Laravel custom error page not displaying for TokenMismatchException

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Whenever I get a `TokenMismatchException` error, the Chrome tools show the HTTP response code is 500.

However, I'm not seeing my `errors/500.blade.php` custom error page.

How can I get this to work as expected?

Comment: Did you try change debug => false in ENV file?

Comment: Hi @QuỳnhNguyễn If I set `APP_DEBUG=false` I don't get the full exception stack, but instead just the "Whoops, looks like something went wrong." message and not my custom 500 error page.

Comment: Please try it xD http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29115184/laravel-catch-tokenmismatchexception

Comment: Yeah I've tried that and it works, but I was hoping to simply be able to create the custom error page since it's returning a 500 error code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel will only use your `[error_code].blade.php` files for instances of `HttpException`. Since `TokenMismatchException` in not an instance of `HttpException` Laravel won't render your `500.blade.php` (out-of-the-box).

As @Comrade pointed out you can change this behaviour within your `App\Exceptions\Handler` class.

To do this you can either explicitly check for the exception in your `render()` method:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof TokenMismatchException) {
        return response()->view('errors.500', compact('exception'), 500);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Alternatively, you can override the `prepareException()` (which is how `ModelNotFoundException` and `AuthorizationException` are handled). To do this simply add the following to your `App\Exceptions\Handler`:

```
protected function prepareException(Exception $e)
{
    $e = parent::prepareException($e);

    if ($e instanceof TokenMismatchException) {
        $e = new HttpException(500, $e->getMessage());
    }

    return $e;
}
```

Don't forget to import `TokenMismatchException` and `HttpException` (`Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException`).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can handle exceptions in `App\Exceptions\Handler.php`

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    // 404 page when a model is not found
    if ($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
        return response()->view('errors.404', [], 404);
    }

    // Custom error 500 view on production
    if (app()->environment() == 'production') {
        return response()->view('errors.500', [], 500);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

You should have 500.blade.php, And `404.blade.php` in your `errors/` directory.

Comment: Any idea why using the `500.blade.php` custom error page doesn't work out of the box in this case?

Comment: I have updated my answer, Please check it out and comment below.