# Laravel exception handler not trapping TokenMismatchException

Tags: php, laravel, exception

I am trying to trap TokenMismatchException in Laravel’s Handler.php

When I mimic a csrf token exception by temporarily removing the token from the form, the local dev version of my site shows me:

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68:
```

But when I change the render() function in Handler.php to look for the exception and handle the error, then it doesn’t work. For instance, if I replace the default code with the below for testing, and take the csrf token from the form, the system returns my 'this was not a token problem' message, and not the 'token problem' message.

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if($exception instanceof TokenMismatchException) {
      return('token problem');
    }else{
      return('this was not a token problem');
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

So, with the default code Laravel seems to recognize the TokenMismatchException, but with my simple test code above, it doesn’t. Can you explain to me what’s going on here?

Comment: Per a comment by [DisgruntledGoat](http://stackoverflow.com/users/37947/disgruntledgoat) on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29116516/1575353), do you have `use Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;` before the class definition?

Comment: I had seen that DisgruntledGoat answer during my searching and had implemented it to no avail so it was not in the current code. Now, by re-including the use statement AND by implementing a http response as suggested by Ian, I finally can trap the exception and redirect to another page telling the user to try again, or whatever I decide. This is my first site created with Laravel - it's a learning curve coming from CodeIgniter!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are it's crashing because the return is expecting a `\Illuminate\Http\Response` from `render()`

```
/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Exception  $exception
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{

    if($exception instanceof TokenMismatchException)
        return response()->json('Token mismatch');

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Remember to use the correct class for the Exception

`use Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;`

Comment: Basically you are returning a string, whereas it is expecting an object to be returned.

Comment: I understand now that the response needs to be a proper http response and you have created a http response with a json formatted string. I am trying that and still getting 'Is NOT token mismatch'. I have appened an implementation of your code suggestion in my question above

Comment: I created a simple form, removed the csrf_token field, then submitted it, it worked fine. Try dumping `$exception`, see what is being caught, it could be something completely different.

Comment: Thanks Ian. Because it's a json return it's a bit messy looking but I can see the first line contains:

    Illuminate\\Session\\TokenMismatchException:  in \/home\/vagrant\/sites\/

Comment: @Wittner It sounds more and more like it's not a problem with the Exception, rather the application is throwing another exception, you need to `dd($exception)` and find out what exception is being thrown..

Comment: dd($exception) gives TokenMismatchException {#178 ▼ which is an object containing error information about TokenMismatch and VerifyCsrfToken...

Comment: @Wittner What is your import at the top, it should be `
use Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;` can you confirm?

Comment: I'd like to mark this as the correct answer but with the inclusion suggested by @Sam Onela Do you want to edit the answer to also include his suggestion, or I'm happy to edit it to save you the hassle and mark it as correct

Comment: @Wittner You mean the answer I gave in the above comment regarding the import?

Comment: "Remember to use the correct class for the Exception" - never saw it! Apologies