# TokenMismatchException is thrown when session expires

Tags: php, laravel, session

Session is set to **1min**
I am using Laravel & I have added the `{!! csrf_field() !!}` in the form

**Scenario**
I am on Login page ... 
 After 1min when session expires and I try to login with correct username and password... an ERROR is thrown saying TokenMismatchException and that error is logged in as local.ERROR

```
local.ERROR: Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException in /home/dchauhan/projects/zonehawk/user-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php:67 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure)) #1 /home/dchauhan/projects/zonehawk/user-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #2 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #3 /home/dchauhan/projects/zonehawk/user-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #4 /home/dchauhan/projects/zonehawk/user-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #5 [internal function]: Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure)) #6 /home/dchauhan/projects/zonehawk/user-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #7 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #8 /home/dchauhan/projects/zonehawk/user-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #9 /home/dchauhan/projects/zonehawk/user-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(62): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #10 [internal function]: Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure)) #11 /home/dchauhan/projects/zonehawk/user-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #12 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #13 /home/dchauhan/projects/zonehawk/user-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #14 /home/dchauhan/projects/zonehawk/user-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #15 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure)) #16 /home/dchauhan/projects/zonehawk/user-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #17 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #18 /home/dchauhan/projects/zonehawk/user-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #19 /home/dchauhan/projects/zonehawk/user-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(59): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #20 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure)) #21 /home/dchauhan/projects/zonehawk/user-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #22 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #23 /home/dchauhan/projects/zonehawk/user-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #24 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #25 /home/dchauhan/projects/zonehawk/user-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #26 /home/dchauhan/projects/zonehawk/user-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(726): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure)) #27 /home/dchauhan/projects/zonehawk/user-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(699): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #28 /home/dchauhan/projects/zonehawk/user-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(675): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #29 /home/dchauhan/projects/zonehawk/user-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(246): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #30 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #31 /home/dchauhan/projects/zonehawk/user-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #32 /home/dchauhan/projects/zonehawk/user-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(44): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #33 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure)) #34 /home/dchauhan/projects/zonehawk/user-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #35 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #36 /home/dchauhan/projects/zonehawk/user-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #37 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #38 /home/dchauhan/projects/zonehawk/user-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #39 /home/dchauhan/projects/zonehawk/user-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(132): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure)) #40 /home/dchauhan/projects/zonehawk/user-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(99): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #41 /home/dchauhan/projects/zonehawk/user-portal/public/index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #42 {main} [] []
```

I have also added the code below in **app/Exceptions/Handler.php**

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof \ErrorException) {
        return response()->view('errors.500', [], 500);
    }

    if ($e instanceof TokenMismatchException) {
        return redirect()->back()->with('flash_error' , trans('general.token_mismatch_message'));
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

**Conclusion**

How can I :

- log the TokenMismatchException as **WARNING** instead of ERROR
- what changes should I make in **handler.php** or say any other file to make sure I show appropriate message on UI i.e. whether its a TokenMismatchException or sesion expired

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Please follow this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29115184/laravel-catch-tokenmismatchexception)